# Can you turn a non-USB audio mixer into a USB mixer?

Tags: usb, audio, interface, mixer

Ok. Pretty sure this sort of thing isn't possible but hey ho,

I have a [Behringer Eurorack UB1202](http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/UB1202.aspx) multi-channel mixer.

I'm just curious if there is any way way to turn it into a USB mixer/audio-interface? Ideally with each channel being recognized separately by the computer.

If it is possible, my assumption would be that I would have to disconnect each channel from the consolidated stereo outputs of the board itself and re-route them to the computer via some sort of USB bridge thingy.

I have no idea, not in any way tech savvy :)

Comment: Is the mixer designed for automated control in the first place?

Comment: No, that conversion isn't possible. But Behringer makes plenty of multichannel audio interfaces for USB.

Comment: I feed my mixer - which also has phantom straight into my soundcard - works perfectly...

Comment: Possible?  Yes.  A worthwhile use of your time?  Probably not.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, USB audio devices are all simple USB sound cards/adapters. Most common ones have analog stereo in, but plenty have multiple channels input as well. Most use the default USB audio drivers. Some have higher quality ADC with better codecs for a better audio.

Since you only need an audio input into the computer, and no automation or computer control of the mixer, just find a decent USB sound card with multiple inputs (or multiple USB devices) and a good audio software.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can hack something.

If you feed sine waves with different frequency into the mixer's inputs, you can feed the output into your sound card, run an FFT over the data and get the fader positions.

But as in attaching an USB interface directly, no, that is unlikely.